# Flutter - Map<String, dynamic> to Map<String, MyObject>

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, dart, iterable

I have a Json that looks like this

```
{
  "marDelPlata" : {
    "business" : {
      "b03":{...},
      "b11":{...},
      "b92":{...},
      "b141":{...},
      ...
  }
}
```

Then I have a class with a method to get the json and decode it into a map

```
class Server {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getDataJSON(String location) async {
    String data = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/test_data/data.json");
    Map dataMap = json.decode(data);
    return dataMap[location];
  }
}
```

And a function that it is supposed to get the map<String, dynamic> and map it to a Map<String, Business>, but this is not working.

```
  final Server _server = Server();

  Future<Map<String, Business>> getAllBusiness() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> map1 = await _server.getDataJSON('marDelPlata');
    Map<String, dynamic> map2 = map1['business'];
    // The next line is not working:
    Map<String, Business> map3 = map2.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, Business.fromMap(value)));
    return map3;
  }
```

I am getting this error: "TypeError: elements is not iterable"

Here is the code from the Business class that creates it from a map

```
  factory Business.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;
    return Business(
      name: map['name'],
      location: BusinessLocation.fromMap(map['location']),
      sectionList: List<Section>.from(map['sectionList']?.map((x) => Section.fromMap(x))),
    );
  }
```

Additional data: I recently migrated my project to FlutterWeb instead of an app. When my project was an app the error I was getting was this: "InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>". I dont know if the migrationhas something to do.

I hope you can help me with this, thank you.

Comment: I suggest that you use a debug breakpoint or use a print statement to see what the contents of map2 are immediately before the code line that fails. This should give you a better idea of how you need to process its content. I am not clear what your map2.map statement is trying to achieve.

Comment: @GrahamD If you print the map2 you get: {
      "b03":{...},
      "b11":{...},
      "b92":{...},
      "b141":{...},
      ...
  }

Comment: @GrahamD The map2 is just a map<String, dynamic>, but I want the function to return a Map<String, Business>. That is why I have to convert the 'dynamic' part of map2 (Wich is also a map) into a Business object using Business.fromMap(*here the dynamic part of map2). I hope is clearer now

Comment: So that is good. There is no async issue as per the answer. You have all the businesses in a map. What are you trying to do with those businesses, extract one of them, extract the contents of each of their maps, what?

Comment: So we are missing the code for your Business class definition and specifically its fromMap method.

Comment: @GrahamD Ok, i'll provide it right now

Comment: ...and MapEntry

Comment: @GrahamD I added the code from the Business class. The MapEntry is not a class i created, it is just a class that dart uses to represent a key-value pair

Comment: I am not a great user of .map, my belt and braces approach would be to use a 'for k, v in map2' loop to stuff map2 content into map3 and use the Business class to convert the map2 v's to Business objects. It looks like dart is objecting to MapEntry not being an iterable but I am not sure.

Comment: @GrahamD yeah I tried that like this: Map<String, Business> map3 = {};
    map2.forEach((key, value) {
      map3.putIfAbsent(key, () => Business.fromMap(value));
    });
    return map3;      I get the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223776/discussion-between-grahamd-and-valen-g).

Answer (score 0):

Well you have an asynchronous function call, and then code that uses date from the asynchronous call immediately after. Since it is asynchronous, there is no guarantee on when the call will finish.

So you can imagine that `map1['business']` may be empty when it is assigned to `map2`.
`Map<String, dynamic> map2 = map1['business'];`

Then you iterate over `map2` with no promise that it actually has data. Try putting code that relies on `_server.getDataJSON('marDelPlata')` in a `.then()` statement.

The `.then()` statement will execute code within only once the function call it is attached to is complete.